# How to respond with plain text using PHP to an Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

I have to get a respond asked with JavaScript and responded with PHP (Yii2 Framework). I get the respond: is HTML code but I need my own data.

My JavaScript file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log('Results from PHP: ' + data); // Problem here
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("Error ");
});
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php    
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
    echo('My favourite color is red'); 
?>
```

The respond of the **browser console** (I only need "My favourite color is red"):

```
Results from PHP: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="h-100">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title></title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="C5Npvp5xY_LuMz_iLyH9DTB9_BtyAUbuJc2HRlyIfq579wjnzTkGgqt2RdBYFsx-BjGwYzdMLZZti75_CLof8Q==">

<link href="/assets/b6930980/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">

<header>
    <nav id="w0" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php">My Application</a>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse" aria-controls="w0-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
<div id="w0-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav nav"><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="/index.php?r=site%2Findex">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/index.php?r=site%2Fabout">About</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/index.php?r=site%2Fcontact">Contact</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/index.php?r=site%2Flogin">Login</a></li></ul></div>
</div>
</nav></header>

<main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
    <div class="container">
                        
    My favourite color is red
    </div>
</main>
```

Maybe there is another way to respond instead of using `echo`.

Comment: To quote my 11 year old nephew... this looks suss > `url: 'http://localhost:8080/',` < that is, presumably the URL of your local root, not necessarily the URL of the file you really want to access over Ajax.

Comment: Exactly. I don't need to access to a file. I only need some text like "My favourite color is red".

Answer (score 1):

That HTML response is is not coming from your specified PHP file. It's likely being added by the framework's layout file (a file that wraps your View or Template file).  To remove it, you'd either write code to specify that you don't want/need a layout or empty the layout file.

I don't know that framework exactly, but many include the option to detect if the request is Ajax and specify a different layout (or no layout) if so.

Comment: *"many include the option to detect if the request is Ajax and specify a different layout"* ... Magento does that ... I'm guessing the framework here is Yii, since the question has that in a tag (granted, that's no guarantee).

Comment: Yes, it is Yii2 Framework. How can I specify a different layout? I will look the Yii documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a php file instead of using a Yii controller? Your action just could look like this:

```
 public function actionTest()
 {
    Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');

    return "Test";
 }
```